# Does a Spring @Transactional annotated method overwrite an @Transactional(readOnly=true) method if called within it?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In the name of reuse, I would like to call a method annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly)` from inside a method annotated with `@Transactional` with exclusive locking.

Simply put, Will this overwrite the shared locking optimizations used for the readonly call?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on value of `propagation` you set for your outer transaction. All that explained really well in Spring documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html